# Select DISTINCT for some columns, and the minimum value for others (What is `Group by`?)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, aggregate-functions

I have a table `TableA` with two columns: `MyName nvarchar(100)` and `MyDateTime DateTime`.  There can be multiple records for each `MyName` that have different `DateTime`s.  I am trying to return a record set that contains each value of `MyName` from the table, with the earliest `MyDateTime` for each one.

This works to return the distinct `MyNames`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT([MyName]) FROM TableA
```

I have tried different `UNION` statements but all my attempts are thrown off by the `DISTINCT()` keyword. The following query, for instance, finds all of the times, not just the minimum value for each:

```
SELECT DISTINCT([MyName]), [MyDateTime] FROM TableA
```

Struggling to come up with correct SQL syntax to accomplish this.  Any help, please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT MyName, MIN(MyDateTime)
FROM TableA
GROUP BY MyName;
```

Comment: Wow - too easy.  Thanks, Raphael.

Answer (score 3):

> All distinct [MyName]s from the table with the earlist [MyDateTime].

You need to `GROUP BY MyName` With `MIN(MyDateTime)`, Something like:

```
SELECT MyName, MIN(MyDateTime)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY MyName
```